# Can I use Python 3.7 with Django 1.11?

Tags: django, python-3.x

We have an existing Django application which uses Django 1.11 and Python 3.6. For some security reasons I have been asked to use Python 3.7. I need to make the minimum changes possible. Do I need to upgrade Django as well? If so , is there any code changes required?

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python 3.7 compatibility was retrospectively added into the classifiers for Django v2.0 in [this commit](https://github.com/django/django/commit/2f7cd7f8ecb01d30c1dfdaefa1c1714db76d2553), even though v2.1 was already out. 1.11 was **not** included.

Discussion on Django tracker is here: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/28814

However, 1.11.x is [LTS release series](https://www.djangoproject.com/s/img/release-roadmap.e844db08610e.png), so maybe if you're lucky that will still be added in a micro version upgrade at some later date.

---

***Edit:*** *Python 3.7 support was added in the micro version upgrade for [Django 1.11.17](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/faq/install/#what-python-version-can-i-use-with-django) (2018-12-03, about 3 months after this question was originally asked)*

Answer (score 5):

According to this page on the Django docs, **support for Python 3.7 was added in Django 1.11.17**.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/faq/install/#what-python-version-can-i-use-with-django

Comment: This answer is more up-to-date. I would add the full link to the question in docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/faq/install/#what-python-version-can-i-use-with-django

Answer (score -1):

["Django 1.11 requires Python 2.7, 3.4, 3.5, or 3.6. Django 1.11 is the first release to support Python 3.6. We **highly recommend** and only officially support the latest release of each series."](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/releases/1.11/#python-compatibility)

In the future, such questions are inevitably asked and answered in the Django docs.